# iOS: AVPlayer plays multiple instances of audio when using controls on lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have set up a function that creates an AVPlayerViewController instance in order to play an audio track (stored in our server).

```
func playAudio(_ url: URL) {
    let avAssest = AVAsset(url: url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAssest)

    audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = audioPlayer

    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])

    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
        self.audioPlayer.play()

    })
}
```

The player works fine while in the foreground. If I go to the lock screen, the audio continues to play. If I press the Pause button in the lock screen, the audio pauses. The problem is, if I then click play on the lock screen, the audio I was listening to resumes, but a second instance of the audio starts playing from the start, so now i have 2 instances of the audio playing simultaneously. If I pause again and press play again, yet another instance of the audio starts playing.

How can I fix this so the lock screen buttons only affect the original audio?

I'm working on Xcode 11, with Swift 4.2.

Comment: Where is the code you use for `MPRemoteCommandCenter` what are you calling when the user presses play from the lock screen? The code you have hear is creating a new VC every time it's called. Is this what you're calling when a user presses play from the lock screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem cannot be reproduced based on the code you showed. Therefore it sounds like you have an extra reference somewhere to `self.audioPlayer`, and the problem is caused by *code you did not reveal to us*.

To test that theory, let's start by not making it a global. There's no need for that within the scope of the question.

Modify your code to look like this (note the changes to make this a local):

```
    let avAssest = AVAsset(url: url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAssest)

    let audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem) // *

    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = audioPlayer

    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])

    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
        audioPlayer.play()  // *

    })
```

Now delete the `audioPlayer` property and, if your code fails to compile, comment out everything that refers to it until the code does compile. Test the app; all is well. Now go back and figure out where in the code you *did not show us* the problem is coming from.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually found out a delegate was causing a conflict.

Comment: Mr. @matt !  you may know this strange one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77150943/avplayerviewcontroller-simply-wont-play-in-the-fullscreen-mode-once-you-tap-th